# Background Image want to stretch automatically based on screen size

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

And also the Image must be stretch automatically based on the screen size

```
body{
    background-image:url("BG URL");
}​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one `background-size:cover`

```
body{
    background:url("myBgUrl");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}​
```

***[more info](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)***

Comment: Very much recommend using `background-size: cover`. For browsers that don't support it, you can use the [polyfill](https://github.com/nsbingham/BackgroundSize).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.classname
{
background: url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat; 
background-position:center center; 
background-attachment:scroll; 
background-size:100% 100%;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this one, It will support all browsers

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
```

Call image

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
    {
     $.backstretch("path/to/image.jpg");

    });
```

you can download js files from here
https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch

Answer (score 0):

```
body
{
background:url(/image/bg.jpg) repeat-x;
}
```

If not working !!!!

```
body
{
background:url(/image/bg.jpg) repeat;
}
```

Hope this helps you.